# Identifying undefined vertical datum

Tags: coordinate-system, datum, vertical-transformation

I was given two DEM files covering the same area of Northern California (lets call them File_A and File_B). They're derived from LiDAR that was flown separately in the last 10 years. My goal ultimately is to compare these two datasets to see change over time. Both files have undefined vertical datums.

**File_A** has decent metadata and I was able to identify the vertical datum as NAVD88.  This also checks out when I compare actual elevation data points from a known good elevation file to File_A's values at that same location. Points are <<1m different. Everything is groovy so far.

Unfortunately, **File_B** doesn't have metadata to confirm the vertical datum.  I'm confident it isn't NAVD88 because pixels across the entire dataset are 9 to 33 meters lower than File_A with no points in File_B sitting higher than File_A (average ~23 m difference).

**So my question**: how would you go about identifying the original vertical datum of File_B so that it can be transformed to match File_A to enable comparisons?

If location is important, here's the center of the files: 120.6°W 40.1°N and they extent ~6 miles in all directions from that point.

Comment: Do you need to actually need to know the File_B datum? Could you not graph and regress every point B against A for common points, and then apply the resultant transformation? It sounds as if File_A has very precise and accurate data against your control points but that might not be the case for File_B points. Perhaps try to establish that first. Having brought both to the best "common level" you could then establish their difference at each point and plot this to see if some areas show differential uplift/fall.

Comment: @LeighBettenay That's the approach we initially have planned. (1) Identify landscape features that haven't changed (parking lots, roads, dams, etc.) spread across the landscape, (2) determine if there is a geographic bias in the datum differences, (3) transform File_B points based on what we learn.  I was posing the question here in the hopes that the SE hivemind had a trick/general knowledge for reacquiring the lost vdatum and making the official transformation without the fudging.